# calculating unique pageviews in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate the unique pageviews for these 2 pages.

- Account with signups ->mysite.com/form?account=true&subscribed
- Account only -> mysite.com/form?account=true

I have this query with the case function but when i run the below query separately for each page parameter i get different results than when running it combined. But the combined result is inaccurate. Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong here?

```
     SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN hits.type = "PAGE" THEN CONCAT(fullvisitorid, 
    STRING(visitid), hits.page.pagepath) END)) AS UniquePageViews,
    CASE WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(.*account=true)'))  THEN "Accounts" 
    WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(.*subscribed)')) THEN "Signups" ELSE "Others" END AS Goals
    FROM
     [mydata.ga_sessions_20150506]
    GROUP BY
     Goals
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the cases where both strings `"account=true"` and `"subscribed"` are present in the same `pagePath`, so when you try counting them only one is considered.

One way of solving it could be by changing the matching condition, such as:

```
SELECT
    EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(CASE WHEN hits.type = "PAGE" THEN CONCAT(fullvisitorid, 
STRING(visitid), hits.page.pagepath) END) AS UniquePageViews,
    CASE WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(account=true)') AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(subscribed)'))  THEN "Accounts" 
         WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(subscribed)') AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(account=true)')) THEN "Signups"
         WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(subscribed)') AND  REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(account=true)')) THEN "Both"
         ELSE "Others" END AS Goals
FROM
 [mydata.ga_sessions_20150506]
GROUP BY
 Goals
```

Where I forced the condition to match only `"account=true"` and not `"subscribed"`.

As an example, here's what I tested on our ga_sessions dataset:

```
SELECT
exact_count_distinct(CASE WHEN hits.type = "PAGE" THEN CONCAT(fullvisitorid, STRING(visitid), hits.page.pagepath) END) AS UniquePageViews,
CASE WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(colcci)') AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(lacoste)'))  THEN "colcci" 
     WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(lacoste)') AND NOT REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(colcci)')) THEN "lacoste"
     WHEN (REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(lacoste)') AND REGEXP_MATCH (hits.page.pagePath, '(colcci)')) THEN 'both'
     ELSE "Others" END AS Goals
FROM [40663402.ga_sessions_20150506]
GROUP BY
Goals
```

Hope this helps. Any questions let us know,

Comment: i am getting the same results as before. Maybe an issue with unique pageviews?
I tested this below query for uniquepageview and i am getting the accurate number. But i am not sure how to include this query in my example.
SELECT COUNT(1) as unique_pageviews
FROM (
    SELECT 
        hits.page.pagePath, 
        hits.page.pageTitle,
        fullVisitorId,
        visitNumber,
        COUNT(1) as hits
    FROM [my_table]
    WHERE hits.type='PAGE' 
    GROUP BY 
        hits.page.pagePath, 
        hits.page.pageTitle,
        fullVisitorId,
        visitNumber
)

Comment: Not sure what's wrong then. Maybe if you try adding:
`where hits.page.pagepath contains ("account=true&subscribed" or ("account=true" and not "subscribed")` might solve but not sure why the first query didn't work. (didn't test this query as well, might not work)

Comment: Quick question, can you share the results with us of both the query I suggested you and the one you said is correct?

Comment: UniquePageViews/Goals  

62=Both,  331269=Others, 140=Signups,31=Accounts

Comment: @willy, the correct value should be 93=accounts, and 202=signups

Comment: (tried creating a chat but it failed). The interesting thing here is that the correct value should be 202 and my query found 140. But 140 + 62 = 202 (140 plus total pageviews that contains 'Both' `account=true` and `signup`)

(in my query both=62)

Also, my query found 31 accounts and the result is 93 which is also 31 + 62 = 93. So it looks like when you are counting the `accounts` and `signups` you are counting it for each `goal` and not just one. Could it be the case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111798/discussion-between-sam123-and-will).